# Why HTML form cannot be submitted by a button with name "submit"?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to submit a HTML form,

```
<form action="go.php">
    <input id="I" type="button" name="submit" value="Go" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
</form>
```

The code above failed, but if I change the name of button to something else, for example,

```
<form action="go.php">
    <input id="I" type="button" name="bt" value="Go" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
</form>
```

it works. Why? What's the difference between these two?

Comment: when you want to submit, why you want to use type="button". use type="submit"

Comment: In your browser console window you are likely to see a message like: `Uncaught TypeError: this.form.submit is not a function`. This hints at the problem, and @Pointy's answer below explains it best.

Answer (score 5):

Interactive elements that are in a form and that have "name" attributes are associated in the DOM graph with the form DOM node as properties of the node. The property names are taken from the "name" attributes on the interactive elements.

Thus, if you look at the form node via the developer console, you'll see properties corresponding to your input elements, buttons, textareas, selects, etc. So, given:

```
<form id=myform>
  <input name=sometext value="hello world">
</form>
```

then this would work from JavaScript:

```
var f = document.getElementById("myform");
alert(f.sometext.value); // "hello world"
```

This weird behavior causes problems when you use names that collide with other useful properties on the form DOM node, like "submit". The reference to your button via the name "submit" has overridden the reference to the "submit" function that was there when the form node was "born".