# Why does this form not submit when using jQuery submit function

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit

I have the following form that is not submitting when I click the html button that has a jQuery submit function attached to it's click event.

My html is below:

```
<form data-role="tocart-form" name="dynamicForm" id="dynamForm" action="http://www.example.com/dynamicbuy.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="product" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="uenc" value="aHR0c"> 
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="eG4oiXalmxVw4hDx">
<input name="price" type="hidden" value="">
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Buy" class="buttonBuy">
</form>
```

My jQuery is below:

```
$(".buttonBuy").click(function(){
        $("input[name='price']").val($("#the-watchPrice > span").html());
        $("#dynamForm").submit();
    });
```

Comment: See [Why does naming your HTML form submit button “submit” break things?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876243/why-does-naming-your-html-form-submit-button-submit-break-things) Also, [Why HTML form cannot be submitted by a button with name “submit”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014765/why-html-form-cannot-be-submitted-by-a-button-with-name-submit) and [How send a form with Javascript when input name is “submit”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729319/how-send-a-form-with-javascript-when-input-name-is-submit)

Comment: Also, per jQuery [`submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) documentation: "Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that conflict with properties of a form, such as `submit`, `length`, or `method`. Name conflicts can cause confusing failures."

Answer (score 1):

Your `<input type="button" name="submit" value="Buy" class="buttonBuy">` needs to be `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"` in order to submit the form.

In addition to this, you appear to be doing custom jQuery validation / submission. To trigger this, you'll need to prevent the *default* form submission by passing the submission event into the click function, and preventing it with `.preventDefault()`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
$(".buttonBuy").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("input[name='price']").val($("#the-watchPrice > span").html());
  $("#dynamForm").submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form data-role="tocart-form" name="dynamicForm" id="dynamForm" action="http://www.example.com/dynamicbuy.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="product" value="4">
  <input type="hidden" name="uenc" value="aHR0c">
  <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="eG4oiXalmxVw4hDx">
  <input name="price" type="hidden" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy" class="buttonBuy">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, just change the name of the submit button to something other than submit as below:

```
<input type="button" name="buybutton" value="Buy" class="buttonBuy">
```

You can view an working [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/tejsoft/72Lnaw8p/)